# ¿Cómo puedo hacer http-ping a un servidor cualquiera a través de NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, http

Trabajo en NodeJs, quiero hacer un comando en el cual, el programa hace un **http-ping** a un servidor especificado en el primer parámetro del comando.

Cuando un usuario escriba `$ping google.com`

El programa debe ejecutar el ping al servidor google.com, y devolver la velocidad en ms.

Los parámetros están ordenados en un array, así que `params[0]` sería el enlace que el robot debería hacer ping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Hacer ping con Promises

Trabajaremos usando `http` para obtener el ping de una página web.

> var http = require("http");

Si lo quieres hacer en forma de función (que devuelve el tiempo de respuesta), usa el siguiente código. La ventaja de éste código es que puedes ponerlo en cualquier parte del código, y ejecutarlo desde varios puntos sin tener que repetir el código. Lo malo es la dificultad que tiene.

```
function ping(url, port) {
  var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var result;
    var options = { host: url, port: port || 80, path: '/' };
    var start = Date.now();
    var pingRequest = http.request(options, function () {
      result = Date.now() - start;
      resolve(result);
      pingRequest.abort();
    });
    pingRequest.on("error", function () {
      result = -1;
      reject(result);
      pingRequest.abort();
    });
    pingRequest.write("");
    pingRequest.end();
  });
  return promise;
}

ping(params[0], 80)
  .then(time => console.log(`Response time: ${time}ms`))
  .catch(error => console.log(`Failed to ping: ${error}`));
```

(Recuerde que la función devuelve un promise, así que debe usar `.then()` y `.catch`, en caso contrario, recibirás un `{ <resolve> Promise }` de respuesta.

La otra manera de hacerla es trabajarla directamente de la siguiente manera:

```
return Promise.all([
  new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var result;
    var options = {
      host: params[0],
      port: 80,
      path: '/'
    };
    var start = Date.now();
    var pingRequest = http.request(options, function() {
      result = Date.now() - start;
      resolve(result);
      pingRequest.abort();
    });
    pingRequest.on("error", function() {
      result = -1;
      reject(result);
      pingRequest.abort();
    });
    pingRequest.write("");
    pingRequest.end();
  }),
])
.then(ping => {
  console.log(`HTTP ping (to ${params[0]}): ${httpping}ms`);
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log(`Ping Error:\n${err}`);
});
```

Éste código mandará un paquete ping al servidor especificado mediante HTTP, y si el ping se ha realizado con éxito, ejecutará el código dentro del `.then()`, en la que `ping` es el tiempo de respuesta. Si existe algún error y el ping no se pudo ejecutar, se ejecutará el código dentro del `.catch()`.

## Hacer ping con librerías externas

Aunque casi seguro necesitarás hacer un Promise dentro de otro.

Sin embargo, la otra solución para NodeJs (usando librerías de terceros) está en el este [enlace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-http-ping).

Ejecuta el siguiente comando para instalar **node-http-ping**

> npm install node-http-ping --save

Entonces, en su programa, usted deberá definir el paquete recién instalado.

> const ping = require('node-http-ping');

Y posteriormente, ya usa el código como usted quiera, `params[0]` es el parámetro que contiene el enlace, entonces, usted deberá hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
ping(params[0])
  .then(time => console.log(`Response time: ${time}ms`))
  .catch(error => console.log(`Failed to ping: ${error}`));
```

Éste código ejecutará un ping al servidor especificado, si ha sido encontrado, mandará un `console.log` mostrando el tiempo de respuesta. Si el servidor no ha sido encontrado, recibirá un error en su consola.

Comment: Mas que una respuesta, esto parece la promoción de un software concreto.  Además, ¿ que es un *http-ping* ? Ese paquete lo que hace es un `GET /`, que es simple de realizar en Nodejs mediante `http.request`.

Comment: Era algo que encontré en Google y funcionó, aunque tengo que resolver un promise para mostrar el tiempo de respuesta. Tu respuesta parece mejor (por el hecho de que usa el paquete `http` directamente), ¿puedes escribirla con más detalle?

Comment: No tienes mas que echarle un vistazo al código del módulo que indicas, `node-http-ping`; estará en tu *path* `node_modules/node-http-ping`, o, si lo prefieres, en su página de GitHub [https://github.com/Seikho/node-http-ping/blob/master/src/index.js]. Son apenas 20 líneas, muy fácil de leer. De extra, muestra como usar las *promises* del paquete *bluebird*; apenas 3 de las 20 líneas son relativas a esas *promises*.

Comment: Editado, ¿le importaría revisarlo?

Comment: Hay un paquete para hacer ping llamado [tcpie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tcpie). Obtienes el tiempo de respuesta por cada paquete, los estados de los paquetes obtenidos y el tiempo total de la respuesta.

Comment: Ahora mucho mas mejor ;-)